# Filter Out Dropdown Values in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have two problems. First is once I click the button again if the dropdown is opening, it should close. Second, I need to filter out the values that are shown on it. Once it has been selected, it should disappear from the available options?

Check my code sandbox here

[image: Edit dropdown]

```
<DropdownMenu show={isComponentVisible} ref={ref}>
  {statuses.map(({ id, statusName }) => (
    <MenuButton
      type="button"
      key={id}
      onClick={() => handleSelect(statusName)}
    >
      {statusName}
    </MenuButton>
  ))}
</DropdownMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, you set `isComponentVisible` to `true`, but `handleClickOutside` is called as well, and sets it to false:

```
const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
  if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
    setIsComponentVisible(false);
  }
};
```

The `handleClickOutside` should ignore the button. You can create another ref for the button. For example:

```
const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
  if (
    ref.current &&
    !ref.current.contains(event.target) &&
    buttonRef.current &&
    !buttonRef.current.contains(event.target)
  ) {
    setIsComponentVisible(false);
  }
};
```

To filter the items, according to the current one, just add a simple filter to your main component:

```
const currentStatuses = status
  ? statuses.filter(s => s.statusName !== status)
  : statuses;

return (
  <MainContainer>
    <DropdownContainer>
      <Dropdown
        status={status}
        statuses={currentStatuses}
        handleSelect={handleSelect}
      />
    </DropdownContainer>
  </MainContainer>
);
```

[image: Edit dropdown]

Comment: Thank you. However when I click outside of the dropdown/button, dropdown should close. Another thing, Do we need useCallback etc... to improve performance/prevent rerendering?

Comment: Just stupid typos. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @SanketShah. I had to reject it, because I was editing the answer myself.

Comment: Thanks. do we need use useCallback or other hooks?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but you are adding and removing events to the body on every change, so you might want to set `handleClickOutside` as a dependency for the `useEffect`, and that would require `useCallback`  on `handleClickOutside` to prevent it from calling changing all the them. However, you should profile the performance before pushing too many `useCallback` calls around.

Comment: Thank you. can you add it also on your codesandbox?

Comment: Out of the scope of the question. I gave you the direction, try it.

Comment: No problem. Thank you